# bitbucket Pipelines - aws: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, pipeline

I have a pipeline to AWS S3. My build fails for the following reason.

> ./devops/scripts/deploy-production.sh: line 35: aws: command not found

In my deploy-production.sh script at line 35 I have the following code:

```
aws s3 cp $BUNDLE $S3_BUCKET_ENDPOINT > /dev/null 2>&1

aws deploy create-deployment \
  --application-name $APPLICATION_NAME \
  --deployment-config-name $DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG_NAME \
  --deployment-group-name $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME \
  --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE \
  --s3-location bucket=$S3_BUCKET_ENDPOINT,bundleType=tgz,key=bundles/$BUNDLE
```

I pulled in the AWS via a script called prior to the above script (build-for-production.sh):

```
npm run build

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
rm -rf ./aws
rm -f awscliv2.zip

# clean up
rm -rf ./aws
rm -rf awscliv2.zip
```

Then in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
- step:
        name: 'Deploying to Production'
        deployment: production
        #        trigger: 'manual'
        script:
          - bash ./devops/build-server.sh
          - bash ./devops/build-for-production.sh
          - bash ./devops/scripts/deploy-production.sh
```